# email still has a value even though I unlinked - Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I used Unlink('google.com') to unlink a user's emaill account, leaving them with only an phone auth. I looped through user.providerData to confirm the only providerId are phone auth. However, printing user.email, I still see the value of the previously added email. I'm expecting this value to be null since I've removed/unlinked the email.

==============================================================================================
i had a problem phone authentication and google authentication when i tried to unlink one of them from the application unlink() function it temporary unlinked then it back on firebase (only the icon removed from the firebase after sign-in with google again it's back) i hope any one helping me in this issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the token lives in your application **for one hour**.
Try to check again after one hour to see if the information is still there.
I had similar issue when I try delete an account from Firebase Auth, but it could still access until 1 hour passed., then it was fine.

Comment: Do you still need this?